# How many possible values does N have given the following conditions?

Tags: number-theory

[image]

**MyAproach**

$68488$/N and $67516$/N leave Same Remainder.N is also a 3 digit number.So,I think it can have have its value from $100$ to $999$.Possible values I found by subracting the two numbers and I get=$972$.

By taking its factors there are $6$ $3$ digit numbers it can have that can possibly leave a same remainder.

$1$ . $972$

$2$ . $486$

$3$ . $324$

$4$ . $243$

$6$ . $162$

$9$ . $108$

So,I think the possible values are $6$.
And the Ans is B

> Am I right in my approach.Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: It is  the right approach, and right answer.